# How to access second cell of each row in a html table using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was trying to access every second cell of each row in a table, but it doesn't seem to be working and just shows a bunch of undefined variables. Is there any way that I can do this? Any help would be appreciated.

**Example table :**

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Data 1A | *Data 1B* | Data 1C |
| Data 2A | *Data 2B* | Data 2C |
| Data 3A | *Data 3B* | Data 3C |

Note : I was trying to access the italic data cell.

```
 let table = document.querySelector("table");
 
 for (let row of table.rows) {
  
      for (let cell of row.cells) {

           console.log(cell[1]);

      }

 }
```

**Output :**

```
Undefined
```

**Expecting output :**

```
<td>Data 1B</td>
<td>Data 2B</td>
<td>Data 3B</td>
```

Comment: Did you try using [:nth-child() Selector](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: please also include the input html.

Comment: `cell[1]` undefined, try `row.cells[1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please see:

```js
const tbl = document.querySelector("table");
for(let row of tbl.rows) {
  console.log(row.cells[1].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>td 0.0</td>
      <td>td 0.1</td>
      <td>td 0.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td 1.0</td>
      <td>td 1.1</td>
      <td>td 1.2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In your code you are trying to reach the index of inner value of the iterated cell as:

```
for (let cell of row.cells) {
    console.log(cell[1]);
}
```

which is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution:

```
let secCellList= document.querySelectorAll("table tbody tr td:nth-child(2)");
    secCellList.forEach(secondCell=>{
    console.log(secondCell.innerHTML);
})
```